# flask-restful : The requested URL was not found on the server

Tags: python, flask-restful

I am trying to follow the documentation of flask-restful and tried to run the following code.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

todos = {}

class TodoSimple(Resource):
    def get(self, todo_id):
        return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}

    def put(self, todo_id):
        todos[todo_id] = request.form['data']
        return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}

api.add_resource(TodoSimple, '/<string:todo_id>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But when I tried to run it with "http://127.0.0.1:5000/todo1" URL it responds with the message "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.". What am I doing wrong with the code. Please help.

Comment: Running your code one to one results with `127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jan/2017 12:12:17] "GET /todo1 HTTP/1.1" 500`. Anyway, I assume you defined in your real code `todos` collection with some data. Can you show your traceback while getting the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the way you defined the url route for your resource. Right now you are trying to access it via `http://127.0.0.1:5000/todo1` but you have defined `TodoSimple` to serve requests sent to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/1`. I would recommend to change the code to sth like below

```
api.add_resource(TodoSimple, '/todo/<int:todo_id>')
```

and then, try to access it via `GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/todo/1`

Comment: Not helpful. Still the same problem!!

Comment: hm, works for me, can you edit the question with the changes that I suggested?

Comment: Its working now.. The problem was gone when I restarted my PC. Your help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: you can show the appreciation by upvoting my answer ;)

Comment: I don't own the threshold reputation required to upvote an answer. So, will certainly upvote next time :) !!